# Custom rule for validating an input text box for non english characters using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working on an application using MVC 3 and knockoutjs library. Also I am reseraching the knockout validation plugin. I need to validate an input text value for allowed symbols. As far as I can see, there are not native rules for these so I will have to create a custom one. The bad thing is that my knowledge in regular expressions and javascript is very poor. I need to write a custom function that validates a text box input field and does not allow non-english characters. All the other symbols are permitted. I think I will be able to create the custom rule, but I need the regular expression that validates the input field. Any help with a working example will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does not allow non-english characters

and

> All the other symbols are permitted

seems contradicting to me but I'll try to help :)

First you should **consider using Ajax for validation since server-side languages usually have much better support for Unicode**. If it's not an option then first add [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library with [Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) to your page.

To create a Unicode-aware regular expression use the following form:

```
var englishLettersOrSymbols = XRegExp('[\\p{^Letter}\\p{Latin}]*');
```

Here we say that we accept zero or several (`... *`) symbols and each symbol is either (`[ ... ]`) non-letter (`\\p{^Letter}`) or letter from basic Latin alphabet (`\\p{Latin}`).

Now your custom validation rule would look like this:

```
ko.validation.rules['englishLettersOrSymbols'] = {
    validator: function(value){
        var rule= XRegExp('[\\p{^Letter}\\p{Latin}]*');
        return rule.test(value);
    },
    message: 'Sorry, {0} this is not valid'
};
```

and you would use it in your code like this:

```
var vewModel = {
    // ...
    myField: ko.observable().extend({englishLettersOrSymbols: true}),
    // ...
};
```

---

**Edit:** Removed `|` from regexp. Thanks, [@slevithan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1421022/). It wasn't an error *per se* since `\\p{^Letter}` already included `|` symbol and, thus, the regular expression would still work. However, it was quite misleading.

Comment: I meant all other symbols are allowed. Thank You Andrew for your response. I am wondering why should I use XRegExp library ? I am now reading the specification for test() method and if I pass to pattern only the allowed symbols and check them for match this will do the job.

Comment: Like I said by default JavaScript regular expressions aren't Unicode-aware. So without XRegExp I wouldn't be able to write `\\p{^Letter}` for example. These names inside curly braces are names of Unocode classes and JavaScript regexp engine simply doesn't know them.

Comment: @Andrew, you shouldn't include `|` in character classes to mean "or". It doesn't. What you're doing is simply adding the vertical bar to the list of characters that the character class can match. I.e., `[a|b]` is equivalent to `(?:a|b|\|)`.